# Two ropes problem in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given two ropes, each 1 ft long. You can burn them however you like.  For the first rope, you have $\Omega_{1}= [1,2]$, i.e.  1ft, and for the second one you have $\Omega_{2}= [3,4]$ , i.e.  1ft. Consider $\Omega:= \Omega_{1}\cup \Omega_{2}$, and $(\Omega,\mathcal{B}(\Omega),\mu)$ a measure space where $\mu$ measures how long each measurable set takes to burn.  Each rope takes one minute to burn, i.e.,$\mu(\Omega_{1}) =\mu(\Omega_{2}) = 1$.  Note that the Radon-Nikodym derivative ofμwith respect to the Lebesgue measure is unknown to us. The goal is to use the two ropes by burning them in such a way to measure 45 seconds or 50 seconds described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7LhQrZdpIc.

I have several questions:

1. How can we mathematically prove that burning both sides of a rope takes only 30 seconds in this setting?
2. How can we show that it only takes 50 seconds in the limit by keeping the 3 flames rules in the video?